# Debugging cryptic "Error: cannot import name <Name>" on Django

Tags: django

Sometimes when I run `manage.py` I get a cryptic message in red that says `Error: cannot import name <Name>` and nothing else.

Obviously, this is a simple import or syntax error and with a little looking around, I can usually fix it.  Other times however it takes me quite a while to figure out what exactly I did wrong.  Is there a way to get Django to spit out more info in this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an annoying problem. Luckily, it's been fixed (recently): see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16397) and [this patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17197).

If you want to just hack your local django install (you're running under virtualenv or buildout, right?), change to the root of your django directory (the one with README, INSTALL, etc) and run this:

```
curl "https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17197?format=diff&new=17197" | patch -p3\
```

So, if you run django trunk > 17197, apply the patch to your django install (it applied to django 1.2 for me), or wait until django 1.4, you'll be able to do this:

```
./manage.py shell --traceback
```

And you'll get a full traceback instead of just the Error: cannot import ...

Voila!

Comment: Yes, virtualenv ftw.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

this happens when a circular import appears, when one model is dependent on another and in turn they try and import each other while executing code.

You might want to paste the two models that are causing you issues.

That'll help us debug.

Also it tends to happen sometimes with signals so if you have a signals file please paste too.

Comment: As stated in the question, I'm aware that it's usually an import error or a syntax error.  I've already fixed the issue.  What I want is an efficient way to debug this the next time it happens.