# Not able to run python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, centos, django-haystack, six

**I am not able to run `python manage.py shell`**, I am getting the following exception:

```
[root@dd dase]# python manage.py shell
Error: cannot import name six
```

**But `six` is installed on the server:**

```
[root@dd dase]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 18 2012, 14:18:47) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.9.0'
```

**Django Version:**

```
[root@dd dase]# django-admin --version
1.2.7
```

Nothing in traceback:

```
[root@dd dase]# python manage.py shell --traceback
Error: cannot import name six
```

Comment: what is the django version?

Comment: Could you please provide `python manage.py shell --traceback`?

Comment: @PauloPessoa: django version is 1.2.7

Comment: @pacholik: same result by using `--traceback`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797685/538471 . Perhaps you have a file called six.py in your project root?

Comment: [The download django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) page doesn't have 1.2.7 as a supported version so is it an option to upgrade? otherwise, do you have more than one install of python on your machine?

Comment: Just update the django version to >= 1.4.5

Comment: @PauloPessoa and all:  we can not because we have to test all our projects for new version. Without migration of django version, there is any solution? like insert path of six in any py file?

Comment: @PauloPessoa : Is there is any other-way to do this without changing django version?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a package you have installed that's trying to use django.utils.six which became available in 1.4.2 ([No module named six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100454/no-module-named-six)). Definitely upgrade your django version as given above.